# How to make left aligned italic labels

Tags: graphviz, dot

I know there's `\l` for left aligned line breaks and also `<I></I>` for italic text in HTML labels, but how would I make left aligned italic labels?

Answer (score 0):

Those escape strings for alignment seem to work only in regular labels. However, when using HTML-based strings for node labels, you may use the `align` attribute.

The following example shows the use of align for table cells `td` and within the text of a table cell using line breaks `br`:

```
digraph G {

n[shape=rect, label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">

<TR><TD colspan="3">Very very wide text in the first line</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD width="1" align="left"><i>one</i></TD>
<TD width="1" align="center">two</TD>
<TD width="1" align="right">three</TD>
</TR>

<TR><TD colspan="3">More wide text without meaning
    <br/>
    <i>four</i>
    <br align="right" />
    <i>five</i>
    <br align="left" />
    </TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
>]
}
```

In case you're looking for a simple solution and aren't into HTML-like labels, and the entire label has to be italic, then you may also use an italic font:

```
graph {
    n[width=2, label="left\l", fontname="times-italic"]
}
```

Your fontname may vary, depending on your system (see also [`fontname`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fontname))